# Rails 3 & Ajax date_select onchange => submit

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, onchange

I'd like my date to get saved anytime I change my date via ajax, is this possible? I tried

```
<%= form_for @dates,:remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.date_select :booking_date,:onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

but it does nothing, any good work arounds?

Answer (score 3):

From the rails documentation:

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Because onchange is an html option you need to provide an empty set of options to date_select, otherwise it assumes onchange is a date_select option.

You should change your call to date_select to look like this:

```
f.date_select :booking_date, {}, :onchange => "this.form.submit();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including this in your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```