# Invoke a javascript when date_select value changes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

```
<%= date_select(:production_month, :date, order: [:month, :year], :start_year => @start_year, :end_year => @end_year) %>
```

I have the above date_select in one of my Rails forms.

I would like a javascript function to be invoked when the value on the above date_selected is changed.

I wrote the following javascript block in my code to handle this:

```
$('#production_month').change(function () {alert("Yayyy!!!")});
```

But this javascript function never gets called  no matter what value I select in my date_select.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Comment: Make sure you have added `jquery` in project. also are you sure that `production_month` date select have id `#production_month`?

Comment: @gabbar      1. I have included jQuery in my project. There are other jQuery functions that I am using currently which work fine.      2. I have not declared an id explicitly for my `date_select`. It has only the single line I have shown above. So what would be the id in this case? Else, how can I declare an id explicitly for my `date_select`? Should I use a `select_tag`?

Comment: Can you inspect `date_select` in browser there you will be able to get id of that html field.?

Comment: `production_month_date_2i` was the id. I used that id and the javascript gets called now! Thanks much!

Comment: Would you allow me to write answer for it for future SO searchers as well?

Comment: Please be my guest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `id` of element by inspecting element in browser or you can also set `id` explicitly.

```
<%= date_select(:production_month, :date, order: [:month, :year], :start_year => @start_year, :end_year => @end_year, html_options: {id: 'production_month', class: 'my_css_class'}) %>
```

Then use this id in jQuery event

```
$('#production_month').change(function () {alert("Yayyy!!!")});
```

Alternatively, you can try this too

pass `onchange: 'method();'` in `html_options`

```
<%= date_select(:production_month, :date, order: [:month, :year], :start_year => @start_year, :end_year => @end_year, html_options: { onchange: 'fire_on_product_change(this.id);' } ) %>
```

Then define jQuery method `fire_on_product_change` for event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fire_on_product_change(id){
    var id = id;
     // Use jQuery to get any other attribute using id
    // $("#id").val() 
    alert("Yayyy!!!");
  })
</script>
```

Referece - 
 [date select#1](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) & [date select#2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: is there a way to pass the value that was selected in `month` and `year` of `date_select` to the javascript function (in this case `fire_on_product_change()`?

Comment: @Biju No but you can get selected date and value using jquery by id of date_select so you can pass if of element in function and use that id to get selected date or any other things. i'll edit answer please have a look.

Comment: `SequenceNumber.where(:year => 2018, :month => 2).maximum(:busday_of_month)` - I need to run this query inside the javascript function thats'c called when the `date_select` value changes. Only I need to replace `2018` with the year that was selected in my `date_select` and `2` should be replaced with the month that was selected in my `date_select`. Is there a way (to achieve this) to read the `date_select` values inside this javascript function (before doing form submit)? - @gabbar / @mark

Comment: @Biju As i said you can always get selected value but you would need to use some jquery stuffs , you will get lots of answer to get selected value using jqery in select_tag. and alway remember you have id of that attribute on which you are performing change event.

Comment: @Biju Anyway i've answered the original question, consider this to be accepted and create a separate question for your further modification, :)

Comment: thanks much for the reply. I am able to read the value in javascript. But as I mentioned, the problem I have is, I need to run a Rails query using the value that was selected in my `date_select`. If I run my rails query in an erb code inside my javascript function, I cannot use the javascript variables (containing the values selected in my `date_select`) inside my erb code. You see my dilemma?!

Comment: @Biju You will have to call ajax to use javascript variable, you can't use javascript variable for rails inside javascript block. :)

Comment: I understand I cannot use javascript variable inside erb. So to avoid that, Can I read the form data directly inside my erb instead?

Comment: You can feed in the value of the dropdown to the javascript function that you call

Comment: Where you call your JS function:

Comment: { onchange: 'fire_on_product_change(this.value);' }

Comment: @mark @gabbar - thanks much again for your inputs. I see what you are getting at. Just have a couple of more questions though 1) the value thus passed would be a parameter to the javascirpt function that gets called. Now, can I use that javascript variable inside an erb code in that function? That seems to be taking me back to square one doesn't it?    2. will `this.value` pass both the month and year?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to do it through the inbuilt rails methods:

[Rails 3 & Ajax date_select onchange => submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566711/rails-3-ajax-date-select-onchange-submit)

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

In your case:

```
<%= date_select(:production_month, :date, order: [:month, :year], :start_year => @start_year, :end_year => @end_year, html_options: { onchange: 'productionMonth();' } ) %>
```

EDIT: Or with the correct method name that I misread:

```
<%= date_select(:production_month, :date, order: [:month, :year], :start_year => @start_year, :end_year => @end_year, html_options: { onchange: 'fire_on_product_change();' } ) %>
```

Comment: thanks much for your reply. May I ask if `productionMonth()` is the name of a javascript function that'd be called when the value in `date_select` changes?

Comment: No worries and that's right - you just make the value of 'onchange:' match what you've called your JS function

Comment: Whoops just seen I misread what you called your JS function - have edited my answer

Comment: @gabbar the questioner had included a JS method called 'fire_on_product_change();' but has now removed it from the question :)